# AWS Lambda: "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied", "errorType": "ClientError",

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have been working on fetching the s3 (.csv) data through the lambda function and putting it into the dynamodb. I have enabled a **trigger on S3 bucket** so when any file is uploaded to the bucket it automatically the content of the file to the Dynamodb table through the lambda function.

Lambda Function

```
import json 
import boto3 

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
student_table = dynamodb.Table('AgentMetrics')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)
    
    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)
    
    students = file_content.split("\n")
    print("students :",students)
    
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        try:
            student_table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "Agent" : data[0],
                "StartInterval" : data[1],
                "EndInterval" : data[2],
                "Agent idle time" : data[3],
                "Agent on contact time" : data[4],
                "Nonproductive time" : data[5],
                "Online time" : data[6],
                "Lunch Break time" : data[7],
                "Service level 120 seconds" : data[8],
                "After contact work time" : data[9],
                "Contacts handled" : data[10],
                "Contacts queued" : data[11]
           } )
        except Exception as e:
            print("File Completed")
```

I am using a default s3 put even that you can examine below:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test%2Fkey",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "requestId": "38bf7274-98cc-4647-9bca-5f02c30cd2a7",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Although I have given all-access s3 access to lambda. I don't have any idea where this is going wrong. I would appreciate any effort from you guys. Thanks.

Comment: What is your lambda execution role? Are the s3 objects encrypted using KMS? `example-bucket` is your real bucket that you own?

Comment: Having the exact same issue, was there any solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly declare s3:GetObject access in your lambda policy. It is not needed to make your bucket open.

Actually never open your s3 fully unless you really need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the problem is you said you used the default s3 put event for testing the function, but you need to edit the sample data to match your own data (ie s3 bucket etc) then it will work.